# Retrieve the names of employees who have the lowest salary for each department

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the Employee table as follows:

```
Employee (ID, Name, Salary, DepID)
```

Here is the sample data for the table:

```
1, 'John', 10000, 1  
2, 'David', 20000, 2  
3, 'Joe', 30000, 2  
4, 'Bob', 19000, 3  
5, 'Smith', 20000, 3
```

I want to retrive the name of employees that have the lowest salary for each department, this is what I have tried:

```
select ID, Name, Salary, DepID
from Employee
where Salary in 
(
    select min(Salary)
    from Employee
    where DepID in
    (
        select distinct DepID
        from Employee
    )
)
```

But the answer isn't correct, it only printed out:

```
1, 'John', 10000, 1
```

Whereas the correct answer is:

```
1, 'John', 10000, 1
2, 'David', 20000, 2
4, 'Bob', 19000, 3
```

I don't know which part I did wrong, I'm using SQL Server to run this query. Any help to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe using group by department and order by salary desc

Comment: Think about your code. Understand why it does not work. What exactly does your subquery produce as a resultset? It generates a single row, does it not? And that row represents what? The absolute minimum salary of all employees. And note that the subquery is over-complicated. You are throwing logic and functions into that subquery without really understanding what they do. Hint - you need the minimum salary **per department**. Consider carefully (and test) what should happen when multiple persons have the same minimum salary in the same department.

Answer (score 2):

Just another option using `WITH TIES` in concert with the window function `dense_rank()`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  Employee
 Order By dense_rank() over (partition by DeptID order by Salary)
```

**Results**

```
ID  Name    Salary  DeptID
1   John    10000   1
2   David   20000   2
4   Bob     19000   3
```

**Note:**
I used `dense_rank()` to show ties, otherwise you could use `row_number()`

Comment: Didn't even know about `with ties`.  I've been doing this the hard way for years.  Thanks for this.

Comment: @pwilcox The one advantage of being a lazy, lazy man,  :)

Comment: For the compleness' sake, I think `RANK()` would also produce the same results (since the difference between it and `DENSE_RANK()` manifests in anything where the measure obtains a value > 1.

Comment: @BenThul Fair comment.

Comment: @pwilcox Note that this solution requires an extra sort, and is therefore less efficient. The lazy way, but at least it doesn't require a derived table

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a row-numbering solution for this**

```sql
select ID, Name, Salary, DepID
from (
    select *,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by e.DepID order by e.Salary)
    from Employee e
) e
where e.rn = 1;
```

Switch `ROW_NUMBER` to `DENSE_RANK` to get tied results

Answer (score 0):

probably you're looking for something like that:

```
select *
from Employee as e
inner join (
    select DepId, min(Salary) as s
    from Employee 
    group by DepId
) as t on e.DepId=t.DepId and e.Salary=t.s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try join -

```
select 
    t1.Id, t1.Name, t1.Salary, t1.Deptid 
from 
    Employee t1 JOIN
    (select min(salary) salary,Depid from Employee group by Depid) t2
    ON t1.salary = t2.salary and t1.Depid = t2.Depid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution without using join clause, I assume this is the simplest way so far.

```
select Name
from Employee
where Salary in (
     select MIN(Salary)
     from Employee
     group by DepId
)
```